# Proof of Wedderburn's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been going through a proof of Wedderburn's theorem:
[image: Wedderburn's Theorem]
and I'm stuck on the very last part, where the author refers to example 2.1.4. (linked below). I don't understand what $D^n$ means, or why it would be isomorphic to $L$, or why this follows from the example 2.1.4. The chain of isomorphisms he refers to therefore makes absolutely no sense to me. If anyone could clear things up it would be much appreciated!

[image: Lemmas and ex]

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: @pipicito Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology, Philippe Gille and Tama ́s Szamuely.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this explanation underevaluates the difficulty of the task and glosses over too much. That's why it winds up hard to understand.

You can find a much clearer explanation online [in Martin Isaacs' book](http://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isaacs+algebra+graduate+course&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lYBOU4fiM9e1yASK_YCgDQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=wedderburn&f=false) starting on page 189. Start reading section 13E there that ends with this:

> *"It is also true that $D$ is uniquely determined by $R$ (up to isomorphism), but this is more difficult to prove (and therefore more interesting.)*

That is followed by two key lemmas and the proof of uniqueness.

---

I think the wording of "the induced map from $\bigoplus I_r\to M$" is just not helpful.

The point is that all simple $M_n(D)$ modules are isomorphic to each other. So if $S$ is a simple $M_n(D)$ module, then it is isomorphic to each and every $I_r$, and every other simple submodule of $\bigoplus I_r$.

We can only guess that the isomorphism they are interested in is "induced from" the projection homomorphism $\phi:\bigoplus I_r\twoheadrightarrow S$ by the first homomorphism theorem, but it's unclear why they want to jump from this to an isomorphism with a particular $I_r$. It's true that $\bigoplus I_r /\ker(\phi)$ is simple, but even if you write $\bigoplus I_r =\ker(\phi)\oplus N$ and mod out by $\ker(\phi)$ on both sides, there's no guarantee $N$ is one of the $I_r$.

At any rate, it's not important. Just be sure to prove for yourself that the simple right (or left) modules of a simple artinian ring are all mutually isomorphic.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you. I am going to go over the proof you suggested, but for now I'm going to take it as a given so that I can understand how it links in. I've understood what you've said, but I'm having trouble linking it to 2.1.3, so maybe I haven't understood as well as I'd thought. My main trouble is I don't know what the notation $D^n$ means. They get the isomorphism $D^n\cong L$, so using the result you gave me, then since $L$ is a simple $M_n(D)$ module, $D^n$, whatever it is, must also be a simple $M_n(D)$ module. That's all I've gathered about $D^n$, however.

Comment: @JamesMachin $D^n$ means the direct sum of $n$ copies of $D$. That is, $D\times D\times\dots\times D$ $n$ times. The $M_n(D)$ module action is just matrix multiplication on these $n$-tuples.

Comment: Oh I see! I can see how $D^n$ will be isomorphic to each of the $I_r$ at least, because the $I_r$ are rows of $n\times n$ matrices with entries from $D$, and $D^n$ is basically the same thing. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: The last line of the proof of 2.1.3 is evading my understanding though. I know that $D=\text{End}_A(L)$ is an division algebra such that $A\cong M_n(D)$. Suppose there is a second algebra $D'$. I understand that $D\cong \text{End}_A(L)\cong \text{End}_A(D^n) \cong \text{End}_A(D'^m)$ but I don't get the last step, where the author says this must be congruent to $D'^m$. Why must a different algebra $D'$ be equal to $\text{End}_A(D'^m)$ i.e. $\text{End}_A(L)$? Apologies for the onslaught of questions!

Comment: @JamesMachin I don't think that reasoning is very clear either.  I would just find some other proofs besides the one you linked and read them. They are likely to be much better. Later on, you can come back to this and see if you can fill the gaps.

Comment: Ah ok, well I've come to a dead end on the last line of the proof, how annoying! Anyway thanks again for all the help. I'm going to continue trying to find alternative proofs, but the problem is that google only gives me links to things about Artinian Rings, and the word semisimple keeps coming up. I feel like I have to learn a whole new topic at every turn at the moment!

Comment: @JamesMachin The reference I gave in my answer gives a complete proof of what you are asking. Wedderburn's theorem is exactly about semisimple rings (aka Artinian rings with Jacobson radical zero.) The question you're asking is about a special case of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem for simple Artinian rings. The same concept has lots of names: "semisimple ring", "wedderburn ring" "semisimple artinian ring." Finite dimensional algebras are Artinian, in case you didn't know.

Comment: I feel like the prerequisites I'll need to understand the proof in your link are slightly beyond me. I mean I've never heard of concepts such as artinian rings, opposite rings, idempotent, faithful e.t.c, and I don't know what notation such as $eRe$ means. I don't expect you to explain all that to me obviously, but I feel like my (undergraduate) background knowledge is too weak to understand that proof. I was hoping the book I'm using would be self-contained, but that doesn't seem to be the case. If I can't understand this version though, I'll have to go and start reading up on those concepts!

Comment: @JamesMachin Hah! Well, look at what you're faced with: a poorly written proof that is cryptic, and a well-written proof that gives you an excuse to learn a few new things. The latter one is better every day :) I'm sure Isaacs is not beyond you, although you may not understand it right now. His exposition is very careful (especially compared to the text you're quoting above.) Anyhow, you have your choice from several other sources as well. I'd just like to encourage you to get out of this particular book you're working from for a while!

Comment: I guess I'll try to go through Isaac's proof now, but I have no idea how to find out what notation such as $eRe$ means. I can google search for words such as idempotent, but I can't use google for notation. This is why I feel the whole topic is beyond me at the moment; I'm getting caught up at every step of the proof, and I'm not understanding implications the authors think so obvious that an explanation isn't necessary. I can't really back out now though, this is for my dissertation which is due in less than 2 weeks!

Comment: @JamesMachin Yeah... it's really unfortunate you're being required to write a dissertation on a topic you don't have a handle on.  Btw, $eRe$ means $\{ere\mid r\in R\}$, nothing mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

Example $2.1.4$ says in the last three lines that $M\simeq I_1^n=I_1\oplus \cdots \oplus I_1$. This is the isomorphism which you asked about. Hence we have $L\simeq D^n$, and analogously $L\simeq (D')^m$. If you want to have more details, see for example here: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/algebra/wedder.pdf‎.