# Definition of Direct Sum of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been searching the internet, and I can't find a definition for the direct sum of ideals. In a previous question I [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754179/proof-of-wedderburns-theorem/754590?noredirect=1#754590), the author writes $M_n(D) =\oplus I_R$, where the $I_R$ are subrings and left ideals of the matrix ring $M_n(D)$, and are formed by the matrices $M=[m_{ij}]$ with $m_{ij}=0$ for $j\neq r$. $D$ is a division algebra. Is the direct sum only defined for rings, so that we can only consider the direct sum because they are subrings? Any clarification would be well appreciated!

Comment: As subrings (without unit)...or as abelian subgroups of their ring.

Comment: Seems to me it is meant as a direct sum of submodules of the regular module. You can see the definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) - in particular, in the part "Internal direct sum".

Answer (score 6):

The (internal) direct sum is not "only defined for rings." There are analogous versions for other algebraic objects including groups, modules and others.

It turns out that the underlying set of the direct sum of ideals is the same no matter which of the following ways you think of it:

- a direct sum of subgroups of an abelian group
- a direct sum of (non unital) subrings of $R$
- a direct sum of submodules $R_R$
- a direct sum of sub-bimodules of $_RR_R$

The first one is the most general and is already enough: $\oplus_{i\in I}I_i$ is the set of all finite sums of the form $\sum x_i$ with $x_i\in I_i$. It only makes reference to addition, and no module structure.

However, this direct sum already does have a module (in fact a bimodule) structure, since each term in the sum absorbs left and right multiplication into its respective ideal. Ideals are by definition sub-bimodules of $_RR_R$, so in some sense it is natural to think of them as bimodules summing to another sub-bimodule of $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I get that now. There is a part of the example (2.1.4) I linked, where it says that if $M$ is a simple $M_n(D)$ module, then it must be a quotient of $M_n(D)$. I think I get this part: I think $M=M_n(D)/X$ where $X$ is a maximal ideal of $M_n(D)$. So far so good. But it then says that there is an induced map $\oplus I_r \rightarrow M$ which must induce an isomorphism $M\cong I_r$ for some $r$. I have no idea where the induced map comes from nor why it itself induces an isomorphism. I'm so close to proving this theorem... but every line is a new challenge!

Comment: Or anyone else who could point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful. I just need to know what this so called 'induced map' is.

Comment: @JamesMachin I put an answer on the question you linked to. If you found this particular answer helpful, I hope you consider given it an upvote. Thanks!