# How to prove simple associative algebra over C is isomorphic to matrix algebra M_n(C)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules, associativity

This is a problem our algebra teacher left for us. After researching on related topic, I have found out that it is a direct corollary of Wedderburn's Theorem, which is reads as follows: Suppose A is a simple finite F-algebra, then A is isomorphic to a matrix algebra over division ring D, which is a F-algebra , i.e A $\simeq $$M_n{(D)}$. Since the division ring over $\mathbb{C}$ should only be $\mathbb{C}$ itself, if A is a simple associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ , by Wedderburn's theorem, we can derive A $\simeq $$M_n{(\mathbb{C} )}$.

However, my professor expects a more elementary proof without generalizing to general occasions, say, to prove Wedderburn's theorem.

But until now, I have no clue about how to handle the original problem directly. I also check some literature. Some gave me a hint by considering B(a,b) = tr($L_aL_b$), which was proposed by Molien in 1892. But I don't know where to go on.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The proof of Wedderburn at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754179/proof-of-wedderburns-theorem/754590?noredirect=1) sounds good to me, but you don't want to consider it? There is a direct proof for $M_n(\Bbb C)$ by Molien, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=mIjSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=complex+simple+associative+algebra+is+a+matrix+algebra&source=bl&ots=xCNN3_B_wo&sig=ACfU3U2IDm_d6GAonB-TUzo6edxmDOit4g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik_KWP9pzhAhVj8-AKHQAtCwUQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=complex%20simple%20associative%20algebra%20is%20a%20matrix%20algebra&f=false).

Comment: I think you more or less basically: 1) show $A\cong\oplus _{i=1}^nS$ as right $A$ modules where $S$ is a simple right $A$ module; 2) Show $End(S_A)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ in this case; and 3) Note that $End(A)\cong M_n(End(S_A))$ as algebras.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your suggestion! During last week, I have tried to understand the proof of Wedderburn using the language of modules. Could you please give me more description about Molien's work? I have check the book you suggested but cannot find the detailed proof. Thanks again!

Comment: @rschwieb Good idea! Could you please tell me how to show the third step you mentioned: End(A)≅Mn(End(S_A)) ? I think that is exactly where I cannot give a proof.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Miao Well, that is not hard to prove, but perhaps is a little messy. The idea is that you're going to combine the fact that $Hom(M, \oplus N_i)\cong \oplus_i Hom(M, N_i)$ and $Hom(\oplus M_i, N)\cong \oplus_i Hom(M_i, N)$ for finite index sets (it's not true in general for infinite sets, one of them is the product instead of sum, I forget which.) Basically when you have a sum in both positions of $Hom(-,-)$, the result is a matrix of entries from $Hom(M_i, N_j)$.  Hopefully given a map from $M\to N$, you see how to manufacture a complete set of maps $M_i\to N_j$ using restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to formulate the proof of Wedderburn's theorem.

Lemma1:
Suppose A is a simple F-algebra, $\mathcal{I},\mathcal{J}$ are two minimal left ideal of A, then there exists $\alpha \in A$, s.t $\mathcal{I}= \mathcal{J}\alpha$, thus $\mathcal{I}\cong \mathcal{J}$ holds.

Proof:
Noted that $\mathcal{I}A, \mathcal{J}A$ are two-sided ideal of A. Since A has no proper two-sided ideal,  if $\mathcal{I},\mathcal{J}$ are not trivial, then $\mathcal{I}A = \mathcal{J}A =A$, so we can deduce that $\mathcal{IJ}A = \mathcal{I}A=A$ and $\mathcal{IJ}\neq 0$. Let $\alpha \in J$, then $\mathcal{I}\alpha \subset \mathcal{J}$. Since $\mathcal{J}$ is a minimal left ideal and $ \mathcal{I}\alpha\neq {0}$, then $\mathcal{I}\alpha = \mathcal{J}$, then $\mathcal{I}\cong \mathcal{J}$.

Lemma2:
Suppose A is F-algebra, then $End_A(A) \cong A^{op}$.

Proof: By defining a right multiplication action.

Lemma3:(suggested by @rschwieb)
Suppose $M_{i},N_{i},\: i = 1,2,...,n$ are left R-module, then
$$
Hom_R( \oplus_{i=1}^n M_i, N )\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n  Hom_R(M_i, N)
$$
$$
Hom_R(M, \oplus_{i=1}^n N_i )\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n  Hom_R(M, N_i)
$$

Proof: By induction. When n=2, it is obvious.

Back to the proof of Wedderburn's theorem:
Since A is a simple algebra, we can write $A = \oplus_{i=1}^n A_i$, where $A_i$ are the simple A-module. In other words, $A_i$ are the minimal left ideals of A. By lemma 1, the minimal left ideals of simple algebra A are isomorphic to each other. Thus, $A = \oplus_{i=1}^n A_i \cong  \oplus_{i=1}^n A_1$. 
By lemma 2, we have $A^{op}\cong End_A(A)=End_A(\oplus_{i=1}^n A_1)$, where $End_A(A_1)$ is well-defined since $A_1$ is the left ideal of A. With the help of lemma 3, $$
End_A(\oplus_{i=1}^n A_1) = Hom_A(\oplus_{i=1}^n A_1, \oplus_{i=1}^n A_1)\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{i=1}^n Hom_A(A_1,A_1)
$$
$$= \oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{i=1}^n End_A(A_1)
$$ By 
installing every item into the entry of a matrix, we have 
$$
\oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{i=1}^n End_A(A_1)\cong M_n( End_A(A_1))
$$
By Schur's lemma, since A1 is a simple A-module, $End_A(A_1)$ is a division ring, which is denoted by D. Namely, we have $A^{op} \cong M_n(D)$. Then, $A \cong M_n(D)^{op}\cong M_n(D) $, as we desired, where n is the number of minimal left ideals of A and $D= End_A(A_1)$.